# UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'accountController'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I've been following a tutorial video for web development using `Spring`.

[Here](https://github.com/ritesh3004/basicwebapp) is the complete source code.

Following is the error I get when sending a `GET` request to

> localhost:8080/basic-web-app/rest/accounts

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5FM3CiBT2VPYWM2MzRVUG9wSGM

Comment: You should edit your question and paste the code (instead of a link) that is generating the error and the stack trace as well to get help.

Comment: Looks like your service class `AccountServiceImpl` is not managed/discoverable by `Spring`.Try fixing your `context:component-scan` in `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In file `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` you specified package for scan as:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="app.rest.mvc"/>
```

But all services and repositories are placed in the package `app.core`. Because of this Spring can't find classes of services and does not instantiate service beans. Just change package that have be to scanned for the next:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="app.rest.mvc, app.core"/>
```

Then Spring will find all components of the application.